# orden aleatorio sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Dada la siguiente tabla

```
 - id INT usuario VARCHAR(20),
 - usuario VARCHAR(20), 
 - nombre VARCHAR(20), 
 - sexo VARCHAR(1),
 - nivel    TINYINT,
 - email VARCHAR(50),
 - telefono VARCHAR(20),
 - marca VARCHAR(20), 
 - compania VARCHAR(20),
 - saldo FLOAT,
 - activo BOOLEAN
```

> Listar las diferentes marcas de celular en orden alfabético aleatorio

eso de aleatorio no lo entiendo, solo hay dos opciones asc y desc

```
SELECT marca FROM `tblusuarios` 
GROUP BY marca
ORDER BY marca;
```

Comment: Ya investigaste sobre rand() ?

Comment: Usas MySQL? Especifica por favor

Comment: debe ser en ANSI sql o piensas en algún vendedor en particular como ORacle o MySQl?

Comment: estoy con mysql, esa funcion está para mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la función `RAND()` que tomará un valor de manera aleatoria para la columna especificada; en este caso marca

```
SELECT marca FROM `tblusuarios`
GROUP BY marca 
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: SELECT marca FROM tblusuarios
GROUP BY marca
ORDER BY RAND(); falta el group by ,pero gracias por el aporte amigo

Comment: Si @kit perdona es que desde el celular el difícil

Comment: De qué motor hablamos, porque la pregunta tiene solo etiqueta _sql_ y `rand()` no existe en todos los motores.

Comment: @jachguate tienes razón sin embargo el OP lo aclaró en los comentarios de su pregunta

Comment: Excelente, ya edité la pregunta para que quede claro. Un saludo.